# Moving from MWS Orders 2011-01-01 to 2013-09-01 API Not reading data

Tags: php, amazon-mws

Moving from MWS Orders 2011-01-01 to 2013-09-01 API I cannot read the Order data using the sample PHP code they give.

The 2011 version has quite a bit of help, but none in the 2013 version, so I am trying to use the 2011 sample to read the response and I am stuck.

ListOrdersSample.PHP has:

```
 invokeListOrders($service, $request);

 /**
 * Get List Orders Action Sample
 * Gets competitive pricing and related information for a product identified by
 * the MarketplaceId and ASIN.
 *
 * @param MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Interface $service instance of MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Interface
 * @param mixed $request MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_ListOrders or array of parameters
 */

 function invokeListOrders(MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Interface $service, $request)
 {
 try {
 $response = $service->ListOrders($request);

 echo ("Service Response\n");
 echo ("============================================\n");
 echo(" ListOrdersResponse\n");
 if ($response->isSetListOrdersResult()) { 
 echo(" ListOrdersResult\n");
 $listOrdersResult = $response->getListOrdersResult();
 if ($listOrdersResult->isSetNextToken()) 
 {
 echo(" NextToken\n");
 echo(" " . $listOrdersResult->getNextToken() . "\n");
 }
 if ($listOrdersResult->isSetCreatedBefore()) 
 {
 echo(" CreatedBefore\n");
 echo(" " . $listOrdersResult->getCreatedBefore() . "\n");
 }
 if ($listOrdersResult->isSetLastUpdatedBefore()) 
 {
 echo(" LastUpdatedBefore\n");
 echo(" " . $listOrdersResult->getLastUpdatedBefore() . "\n");
 }
 if ($listOrdersResult->isSetOrders()) { 
 echo(" Orders\n");
 $orders = $listOrdersResult->getOrders();
 //print_r($orders); //debug
 //exit(); //debug
 $orderList = $orders->getOrder(); //line 148
```

$orders looks like this in (2011 version):

> Service Response =====================================================
>   ListOrdersResponse ListOrdersResult CreatedBefore 2017-04-05T18:53:56Z
>   Orders MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_OrderList Object (
>   _fields:protected => Array ( Order => Array ( FieldValue => Array ( [0] => MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_Order Object (
>   _fields:protected => Array ( AmazonOrderId => Array ( FieldValue => 026-3851269-0939511 FieldType => string ) SellerOrderId => Array (
>   FieldValue => FieldType => string ) PurchaseDate => Array ( FieldValue
>   => 2017-04-04T18:03:30Z FieldType => string ) LastUpdateDate => Array ( FieldValue => 2017-04-04T18:33:45Z FieldType => string ) OrderStatus
>   => Array ( FieldValue => Unshipped FieldType => OrderStatusEnum ) FulfillmentChannel => Array ( FieldValue => MFN FieldType =>
>   FulfillmentChannelEnum ) SalesChannel => Array ( FieldValue =>
>   Amazon.co.uk FieldType => string ) OrderChannel => Array ( FieldValue
>   => FieldType => string ) ShipServiceLevel => Array ( FieldValue => Std UK Dom_2 FieldType => string ) ShippingAddress => Array (....

$orders looks like this in (2013 version):

> Service Response
>   =============================================================================ListOrdersResponse ListOrdersResult CreatedBefore 2017-04-05T18:35:36Z Orders Array ( [0]
>   => MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_Order Object ( _fields:protected => Array ( AmazonOrderId => Array ( FieldValue => 026-3851269-0939511 FieldType => string ) SellerOrderId => Array ( FieldValue => FieldType
>   => string ) PurchaseDate => Array ( FieldValue => 2017-04-04T18:03:30Z FieldType => string ) LastUpdateDate => Array ( FieldValue =>
>   2017-04-04T18:33:45Z FieldType => string ) OrderStatus => Array (
>   FieldValue => Unshipped FieldType => string ) FulfillmentChannel =>
>   Array ( FieldValue => MFN FieldType => string ) SalesChannel => Array
>   ( FieldValue => Amazon.co.uk FieldType => string ) OrderChannel =>
>   Array ( FieldValue => FieldType => string ) ShipServiceLevel => Array
>   ( FieldValue => Std UK Dom_2 FieldType => string ) ShippingAddress =>
>   Array

With the 2013 version I get the error:

> PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getOrder() on a non-object
>   in   /home/*****/public_html/****/ListOrdersSample.php on line 148

Which is the last line of code pasted above:

```
 $orderList = $orders->getOrder();
```

The 2013 $orders does look like an array with an object in it, but I am not sure how to read it as my coding is not too strong with arrays and objects.

Once I have $orderList I should be able to continue with the sample code and do things like:

```
 foreach ($orderList as $order) {
                            echo("                    Order\n");
                            if ($order->isSetAmazonOrderId()) 
                            {
                                echo("                        AmazonOrderId\n");
                                echo("                            " . $order->getAmazonOrderId() . "\n");
                            }
```

But unfortunately I keep getting stuck at line 148 with the fatal error.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple fix

```
$orderList = $orders->getOrder(); //line 148
```

changed to:

```
$orderList = $orders;
```

And it started working.